# Trailing slash in URL - not behind parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want a trailing slash in my URLs, but not after URL parameters, if there are any.

Currently using:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [L,R=301]
```

Which works for:

```
www.example.com/test => www.example.com/test/
www.example.com/test/more => www.example.com/test/more/
```

but it doesn't work as expected for:

```
www.example.com/test?param=1&rating=3 => www.example.com/test?param=1&rating=3/
www.example.com/test/?param=1&rating=3 => www.example.com/test/?param=1&rating=3/
```

The last ones should end up like this:

```
www.example.com/test?param=1&rating=3 => www.example.com/test/?param=1&rating=3
www.example.com/test/?param=1&rating=3 => www.example.com/test/?param=1&rating=3
```

Comment: If you want to rewrite your URLs (which you apparently do) then a URL like `https://www.example.com/test&rating=3` does not make much sense, `https://www.example.com/test/rating/3` would...

Comment: If you really want to keep those URL patterns then the only approach I see would be to check if the URL contains a literal ampersand ("&") inside the path component. I am not even sure if that is valid, but anyway. So you need to add a condition to check that.

Comment: Updated the question, fixing the parameters

Comment: Sorry, but I doubt that really is your current situation.. Can it be that you only modified the question such that it looks better but that this does not describe your actual setup? Because the rewriting rule you posted certainly will _not_ result in what you claim under "but it doesn't work as expected for". It would have resulted in what you explained before the modification, though. I suggest you take a little more time to revise your question. ;-)